# Does a Hibernate transaction rollback delete "session.flush()"ed entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have been confused about `transaction.rollback`. Here is example pseudocode:

```
transaction = session.beginTransaction()    
EntityA a = new EntityA();    
session.save(a);    
session.flush();    
transaction.rollback();
```

What happens when this code works? Do I have the entity in the database or not?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Short answer: No, you won't have entity in the database.

Longer answer: hibernate is smart enough not to send insert/updates to the DB until it knows if the transaction is going to be committed or rolled back (although this behavior can be changed by setting a different FlushMode), in your case by calling flush you are forcing the SQL to be sent to the DB but you still have the DB transaction to protect you, when you call rollback the DB transaction will be rolled back removing the changes performed inside itself and hence nothing will be actually saved. Note that depending on your configured transaction isolation level perhaps other transactions will be able to see in some way the EntityA you saved for the short while between the save and the rollback.
Also note that flush is called automatically when you try to read from DB, in 99% of the cases calling it explicitly is not necessary. One exception that comes to mind is when unit testing with auto rolling back tests.

Comment: i couldnt think about the hibernate transaction resembling the real DB transaction somehow. thank you ! can you check this question too ? which let me to ask this question that you have answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903872/hibernate-session-save-creating-not-neccessary-insert-statements

Comment: This part of the answer is not correct: "hibernate is smart enough not to send insert/updates to the DB until it knows if the transaction is going to be committed or rolled back". Hibernate WILL send insert/updates to the DB any time the session is flushed, and this can be before it knows if the transaction is to be committed or rolled back.

Comment: @SteveT do you know any scenario where the session will be flushed without calling .flush() or committing the transaction?

Comment: @ilcavero: depends on the flush mode - in some modes, Hibernate will flush before a query. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html for more info.

Comment: hi @ilcavero would it be same behavior if I use delete in place of save in above code ?

Comment: @dextermini yes it's the same thing

Answer (score 22):

When you call `session.save(a)` Hibernate basically remembers somewhere inside session that this object has to be saved. It can decide if he wants to issue `INSERT INTO...` immediately, some time later or on commit. This is a performance improvement, allowing Hibernate to batch inserts or avoid them if transaction is rolled back.

When you call `session.flush()`, Hibernate is forced to issue `INSERT INTO...` against the database. The entity is stored in the database, but not yet commited. Depending on transaction isolation level it won't be seen by other running transactions. But now the database *knows* about the record.

When you call `transaction.rollback()`, Hibernate rolls-back the database transaction. Database handles rollback, thus removing newly created object.

Now consider the scenario without `flush()`. First of all, you never touch the database so the performance is better and rollback is basically a no-op. On the other hand if transaction isolation level is `READ UNCOMMITTED`, other transactions can see inserted record even before commit/rollback. Without `flush()` this won't happen, unless Hibernate does not decide to `flush()` implicitly.

Comment: can you check my other question that has led me to ask this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903872/hibernate-session-save-creating-not-neccessary-insert-statements

Answer (score 12):

I think you get confused with `flush` and `commit`.

`flush()` synchronizes the state with the database, but it is not doing a commit. The state is still visible by transaction, so that you can call rollback to rollback.

So the answer to your question is: no, you don't have the entity (a) in the database.

Comment: thank you mate. my main confusion was to lack the knowledge of the real DB transaction on the DB site.